# Crash apllication without connection to internet

Tags: android

I have a problem, when I use my application with connection everything is cool, but when I turn off the connection my app crashes, I want to know how to make this app work without connection it crash after asyncTask, this is it,

```
class FetchRecentPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loading_message));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            articles = Services.getRecentPosts(MainActivity.this);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

and this is the class I use for connection:

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.i("wa makaynash connexion a sahbé :s", null);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I wanna know how to work all of this, and thanks

Comment: Could you please report the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Post your logcat! Where exactly is your app crashing?

Comment: what is articles in your pgm?

Comment: 05-02 08:44:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at com.mobiblanc.wydadnews.MainActivity$FetchRecentPosts.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:154)
05-02 08:44:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at com.mobiblanc.wydadnews.MainActivity$FetchRecentPosts.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
05-02 08:44:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-02 08:44:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-02 08:44:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(325):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your articles in post execute somewhere?Even if you are check for conncetivity before hitting the server ,there is every possibility that you receive timeout exception or unknown host exception.So pleace your doinbackground code in try catch and in post execute check have null check for articles before you start using it.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how to do it i try with many solution but nothing and i writ this one after many ones,  i used to do it on post execute but nothing happened :s

Answer (score 0):

Use this and try once i was facing the same prob.

in oncreate

```
if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
```

//          new MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
//Your Code

```
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
    }

}
```

and this after oncreate.

```
public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and make a class called Utils and write this code

```
public class Utils {

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: stil nothing happened :( don't know why :s

Comment: did you add the permission in android manifesta.. it works sometime <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: yes i did it before ,  but i think i make some mistakes on the code u give me but  i  really don't know whats happend :s

Comment: Did you make a new class called Utils or you copied the code in your main activity itself??

Comment: i make a new class utlis and i write this code , but still have errors i correct them but nothing happened , i'm still beginner on android i think that's why i make many mistakes .

Comment: thats ok everybody is a beginner at the beginning...:D,

Comment: thank you saad thank you a lot i wil try and try with your code that's would help me a lot

Comment: when i create public class Utils and i copy the code i have error on :

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity)

when i fixed it i have problemes on the code before and finnaly have the same things when i don"t have connexion

Comment: How did you fix it??,, did you import all the stuff ??

Comment: yes i import them , but when i fix some code others shown . :s

Comment: still same problem , the error is : 
The method isNetworkAvailable cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

i make utils as static the code turn on but the crash is always here :s i wanna thank you a lot saad for your time and try to help me thank you a lot